# Simple checks to make my HTTP server faster

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I am running my own webserver on a 384MB VPS from Slicehost to serve a Ruby on Rails application. I am running Phusion Passenger with Apache2.

I currently expect anywhere between 10-200 visits per day.

I am by no means a server admin so I would like to ask anyone who has advice. What are some simple checks I can do to make sure my server is running smoothly and quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Firefox extensions [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) and YSlow! does wonders for tuning your content.

Comment: Yslow is brilliant, and most of what it suggests is very quick and easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

You might start with [Apache performance tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html), check the tuning recommendations for your database (if you're using [MySQL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,92131,92131) or [postgres](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)), and/or consider running nginx to get the most out of your memory.